# Click outside div to hide div in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to make a popup that should appear once a button is clicked and disappear once the user clicks outside of the box.

I'm not sure how to make the div disappear when I click outside of it.

```
var popbox = document.getElementById("popbox");

document.getElementById("linkbox").onclick = function () {
    popbox.style.display = "block";
};

???.onclick = function () {
    popbox.style.display = "none";
};
```

Comment: One question. Many popups have a darkening background. If you have a darkening background then you can just listen for clicks on the darkening background to hide the popup.

Comment: You can do it on your whole-page background, as long as click-handlers for smaller areas within it use stopPropagation.

Answer (score 25):

**Here is the second version which has a transparent overlay as asked by the asker in the comments...**

```js
window.onload = function(){
 var popup = document.getElementById('popup');
    var overlay = document.getElementById('backgroundOverlay');
    var openButton = document.getElementById('openOverlay');
    document.onclick = function(e){
        if(e.target.id == 'backgroundOverlay'){
            popup.style.display = 'none';
            overlay.style.display = 'none';
        }
        if(e.target === openButton){
          popup.style.display = 'block';
            overlay.style.display = 'block';
        }
    };
};
```

```css
#backgroundOverlay{
    background-color:transparent;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    display:block;
}
#popup{
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #000;
    width:80vw;
    height:80vh;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:10vw;
    margin-right:10vw;
    margin-top:10vh;
    margin-bottom:10vh;
    z-index:500;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup">This is some text.<input type="button" id="theButton" value="This is a button"></div>
    <div id="backgroundOverlay"></div>
    <input type="button" id="openOverlay" value="open popup">
```

**Here is the first version...**

Here is some code. If there is anything else to add, please let me know :)

The event (e) object gives access to information about the event. e.target gives you the element that triggered the event.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var divToHide = document.getElementById('divToHide');
  document.onclick = function(e){
    if(e.target.id !== 'divToHide'){
      //element clicked wasn't the div; hide the div
      divToHide.style.display = 'none';
    }
  };
};
```

```html
<div id="divToHide">Click outside of this div to hide it.</div>
```

Comment: The thing is i'm creating a popup box with:
    document.getElementById("linkbox").onclick = function () {
    popbox.style.display = "block";
    };

And I want to hide it once the user clicks outside the box. So I need the code to make the box appear once clicked and disappear once clicked outside.

Comment: This is a great answer, and just to add to that a little bit, you want to set your css as `#popup * { pointer-events:none }` if there's nothing relevant that the user can click within the popup. Otherwise, if an element within the box is clicked, then the id's will not match (will return the child's id) and the script will assume you clicked outside the box.

Comment: That's what happened David... There are relevant things inside the popup.

Comment: Ok, so I understand that you are creating a modal popup. Now I understand. Thank you.

Comment: The problem with pointer events is that if you have a button or another element the needs to be able to be clicked, it will not work. Just like @David Li said.

Comment: So what should I do to make the popup appear and disappear?

Comment: One question. Many popups have a darkening background. If you have a darkening background then you can just listen for clicks on the darkening background to hide the popup.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Now I better understand :)

Comment: Are you going to have input elements inside?

Comment: Yes, just a single input field.

Comment: Ok, sounds good. I'll code a second version now that I know more information.

Comment: You can take a look at my solution as well that uses the parent() tree from a jquery object. Very interested in @www139 's new solution as well.

Comment: I don't think a transparent overlay is the best solution here. This makes it so that if you hover over anything outside the popup, the cursor will not respond to any of the elements. i.e. user gets the popup but presses a button not in the popup -> button will not be responsive until the overlay is gone.

Comment: I agree, but the asker of this question doesn't want a darkening background. If he wants, he can easily change the background color to make it visible without needing to change the html or js.

Comment: It should then require no background at all. I'm not sure why that is such a crucial part to include.  I understand that it is a workaround but it is a completely unnecessary one.

Comment: It makes it easier to manipulate. You only need to listen for clicks on the background overlay to know the you need to hide the popup vs before you had to compare individual inputs from within the popup.

Comment: While it is easier to manipulate it ends up blocking the rest of the DOM with no UI cue that it is doing so. This is fine with a darkening background because the user understands that nothing else is clickable, but if it is transparent it just seems clunky.

Comment: That is true but it is what the asker asked for.

Comment: Fair enough! Good answer overall.

Comment: Good answer, could be much simpler, you only need 2-4 lines of a code.

Answer (score 23):

Here, the idea is to detect `click events` on the page and set the `container’s` display to `none` only when the target of the click isn’t one of the `div` descendants.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <label>Enter your name:</label>
    <input type="text">
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    if (!container.contains(e.target)) {
        container.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

Comment: will this be interrupted by stop propagation?

Answer (score 5):

This is code I use to close my side bar when click outside

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "100px";
    document.getElementById("curtain_menu").style.marginLeft = "100px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("curtain_menu").style.marginLeft = "0";
}

document.onclick = function (e) {
    if (e.target.id !== 'mySidebar' && e.target.id !== 'btn_frontpage_menu') {
        if (e.target.offsetParent && e.target.offsetParent.id !== 'mySidebar')
            closeNav()
    }
}
```

```css
.sidebar {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 50%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.sidebar a,
.dropdown-btn {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1vw !important;
  color: rgb(195, 195, 195);
  display: block;
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown-container a {
  color: rgb(174, 174, 174) !important;
}

.sidebar a:hover,
.dropdown-btn:hover,
.dropdown-container a:hover {
  color: green !important;
  /* background-color: #5c5c5c; */
}

.sidebar .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  font-size: 36px !important;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: right;
  right: 20px;
}

.openbtn {
  font-size: 20px !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  padding: 6px 15px;
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

#main {
  position :absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 100px
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar" style="width: 100px;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn"
        onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
    <a href="">Home</a>
    <div class="dropdown-container">
        <a href="">Job Management</a>
        <a href="#">Request</a>
        <a href="#">Pending</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="curtain_menu">
    <button id="btn_frontpage_menu" class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰</button>
    <div id="datetime"></div>
</div>
<div id="main"> Outside of 'Side Bar' is here
</div>
```

Comment: you should use "display:none" instead of "width:0" ...

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my Solution.**

```
yourFunc=e=>{
  var popbox = document.getElementById("popbox");
  if(e.target.id !=="popbox"){
    popbox.style.display = "none";
    }else{
    popbox.style.display = "block";
    }
}


document.addEventListener("click",yourFunc)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58806417/edit) to include an explanation of your code, saying *why* you wrote it that way and how it compares to the other answers. This will increase your answer's usefulness and make it more likely to be upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

hope this will work for you

```
 <script>
// Get the element
var modal = document.getElementById('modal');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

This code is tested and it's working nicely, thank you.

Comment: Don't you mean, `event.target !== modal`?

Answer (score 0):

Could be done with `onblur` event.

```
// required for focus
divEl.setAttribute('tabindex', '1');
divEl.onblur = event => {
  // hide only if blur occurred outside divEl, ignore its children
  if (!event.currentTarget.contains(event.relatedTarget)) {
    hide();
  }

  // re-focus, if a child took it
  divEl.focus();    
};
divEl.focus();
```

P.S. For IE11 a small hack `event.relatedTarget = event.relatedTarget || document.activeElement;` could be required.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class='icon alk-icon-close'>hidden hire</div>



    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var target = e.target.classList.value
    if (target == 'icon alk-icon-close') ) {
        hidden hire
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`plug this in`

```js
(function(){
// click outside of element to hide it

let hels = [];

window.hidable = (el, excepter, hider) => {
    // hider takes el as the only arg
    hels.push([el, excepter, hider]);
    return el;
}
window.addEventListener('click', e=>{
    for(let i = 0; i < hels.length; i++){
        let el = hels[i][0];
        let excepter = hels[i][1];
        let hider = hels[i][2];
        if(!el.contains(e.target) && excepter !== e.target){
            hider(el);
        }
    }
});


})()
```

`unit test`

```js
/* excepter is the element to trigger panel show */
// example implementation
window.hidable(panel_el, show_panel_button, el=>el.remove());

// other hiders can be:
el=>el.style.display = 'none';
// depends on your show implementation
```

Answer (score -1):

I try may solution but i have 100% working and easy solution for this issue. so when mouse will leave from this DIV then element will hide self.

```
 @mouseleave="item.del = !item.del"
```

try like this way.

```
<div v-if="item.del" @mouseleave="item.del = !item.del"  > Connection</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
el.onmouseleave = function(){
  document.body.onclick = function(){
    el.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.onclick = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score -9):

Okay, here's a jQuery based solution based on any div clicked within the DOM.

```
$('div').on('click', function(e){
    var parents = $(e.currentTarget).parents();
    for (var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
        if (parents[i].id === 'divToHide' || e.currentTarget.id === 'divToHide') {
            // you are in the popup
        };
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This looks at your current element, as well as any of the parents, and checks if the id matches up. If divToHide is in the parents() list, then you keep the popup open.

*NOTE: This requires wrapping your content within a wrapper div or something similar.

Comment: Please do not post `jQuery` answers to `javascript`-only questions. Read the tag.