# How to disable popup?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to close popsup when I click anywhere on window. Just pure Javascript.  Here is JS

```
   function popItUp() {
       var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
       popup.classList.toggle("show");
   }
```

Here is CSS

```
        .popup .show {
            visibility: visible;
            -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
            animation: fadeIn 1s;
        }


        @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
            from {opacity: 0;}
            to {opacity: 1;}
        }

        @keyframes fadeIn {
            from {opacity: 0;}
            to {opacity:1 ;}
        }
```

and here is HTML

```
       <div class="slidecontainer">
           <div class="popup" onclick="popItUp()">i
               <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Some info</span>
           </div>
       </div>
```

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Do you mean a modal or a popup?

Comment: so add click event to the body

Comment: @jmargolisvt https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click outside div to hide div in pure JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33060993/click-outside-div-to-hide-div-in-pure-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to detect the click event on the element. Then stop it from propagating to the document.

And also detect click event on any part of the document, then toggle the class `show`

The `click` event propagates from the element, then to the document. You need to stop it from propagating to the document using `event.stopPropagation()`.

```js
document.onclick = function(){
  document.getElementById('myPopup').classList.remove('show');
};
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction(e) {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

```css
.popup .popuptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */
/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;} 
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

```html
<body style="text-align:center">

<h2>Popup</h2>

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction(event)">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the state of the pop-up. It's the `.show` class. So whenever the `show` class is not on the `div` it will not show, right?

Thus when you click anywhere on the window, what needs to happen is a function needs to be executed where you remove the `show` class from the pop-up div.

Here's an edit with some code:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', fn); 

function fn() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
       popup.classList.remove("show");
}
```

Comment: Won't this remove the popup even if he clicks within the popup?

Comment: It will indeed.