# Close div with click outside (parent)

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, popup, onclicklistener

This is not a new problem on stackoverflow, but I've tried everything without success.

I have a "popup" created with two divs. The parent ist the background and the child is the popup content. I want to hide the popup when the user clicks on the background (the parent).

It sounds extremly easy also for me but I can't achieve that.
This is my code and what I tried (it works exacly at the opposite way as I want):

```js
let content = document.querySelector('.popup-content');
let popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
let button = document.querySelector('button');

button.onclick = () => {
 popup.style.display = 'block';
 content.onclick = e => {
   if(e.target !== this) {
     popup.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.popup {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  display: none;
}

.popup-content {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 25%;
  min-width: 470px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<button>
Open Popup
</button>
<div class="popup">
  <div class="popup-content">
    <h3>Popup Title</h3>
    <p>Popup Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: You're adding a click event only to your popup content, you need to add a click event to the container div

Comment: bind the hide event to the background click and stop propagation in the child click

Comment: Try my best solution for this problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33060993/click-outside-div-to-hide-div-in-pure-javascript/75603215#75603215

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should separate both events and attach the click to the `window` so you can detect the clicks outside of `popup-content` like :

```js
let content = document.querySelector('.popup-content');
let popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
let button = document.querySelector('button');

button.onclick = () => {
  popup.style.display = 'block';
}

window.onclick = e => {
  if (e.target === popup) {
    popup.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
.popup {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  display: none;
}

.popup-content {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 25%;
  min-width: 470px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<button>
Open Popup
</button>
<div class="popup">
  <div class="popup-content">
    <h3>Popup Title</h3>
    <p>Popup Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It was so easy! Thank you very much.

Comment: You're very welcome, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this :

instead of adding the `EventListner` to close the div on the button you need to add it on the `document` instead. and test on `target` if is not your button just like this :

```
    let popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
    let button = document.querySelector('button');



    // Event that hide the popin if the click happen out popin
    function closeHandler(e) {
        if (e.target !== popup) {
            // We remove the event for better perfermance
            removeCloseListner();
            // We hide the popin
            popup.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

    // Call this function when you open your popin popin
    function addCloseLitnerToDocument() {
        document.addEventListener("click", closeHandler);
    }

    function removeCloseListner() {
        document.removeEventListener("click", closeHandler)
    }

    // Add listner to Open Popin
    button.onclick = (e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    // when popin is open
                    // Add listner to the document
                    // And show the popin
                    popup.style.display = 'block';
                    addCloseLitnerToDocument();
                }
```