# Close toggle menu after clicking outside of it and on a link

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle, navbar

I'm currently using this simple toggle menu from w3school.

I was wondering how can this be edited in order to close when clicked outside of it or on a link (Logo, News, Contact, About)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.mobile-container {
  max-width: 480px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #555;
  height: 500px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: relative;
}

.topnav #myLinks {
  display: none;
}

.topnav a {
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  display: block;
}

.topnav a.icon {
  background: black;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Simulate a smartphone / tablet -->
<div class="mobile-container">

<!-- Top Navigation Menu -->
<div class="topnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Logo</a>
  <div id="myLinks">
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h3>Vertical Mobile Navbar</h3>
  <p>This example demonstrates how a navigation menu on a mobile/smart phone could look like.</p>
  <p>Click on the hamburger menu (three bars) in the top right corner, to toggle the menu.</p>
</div>

<!-- End smartphone / tablet look -->
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myLinks");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kjsdfx3v/)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51862116/close-div-with-click-outside-parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to add an Event Listener in the whole document and use the conditional to see where you are clicking. Here's a Codepen with this logic: https://codepen.io/alac1984/pen/RwNVKOe

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<!-- Simulate a smartphone / tablet -->
<div class="mobile-container">

<!-- Top Navigation Menu -->
<div class="topnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Logo</a>
  <div id="myLinks">
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="icon" id="myButton">
    <i id="itag" class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h3>Vertical Mobile Navbar</h3>
  <p>This example demonstrates how a navigation menu on a mobile/smart phone could look like.</p>
  <p>Click on the hamburger menu (three bars) in the top right corner, to toggle the menu.</p>
</div>

<!-- End smartphone / tablet look -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.mobile-container {
  max-width: 480px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #555;
  height: 500px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: relative;
}

.topnav #myLinks {
  display: none;
}

.topnav a {
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  display: block;
}

.topnav a.icon {
  background: black;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

JS:

```
const button = document.getElementById('myButton');
const div = document.getElementById('myLinks');
const icon = document.querySelector('.icon');
console.log(icon);

document.addEventListener('click', myFunction)

function myFunction(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.target);

  if((div.style.display === '' || div.style.display === 'none') && (e.target === button || e.target === itag)) {
    div.style.display = 'block';    
  } else if((div.style.display === '' || div.style.display === 'none') && (e.target !== button || e.target !== itag)) {
    div.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    div.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```