# Click Outside To close Dropdown Avatar Menu

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, menu, avatar

I have this avatar dropdown menu, and you must click the avatar to close the menu, but I want to be able to click anywhere on the page to close the menu. any help would be greatly appreciated.

below is the html, and the javasript

```
<div class="user-menu-wrap">
            <a  class="mini-photo-wrapper" href="page.html" onclick="return false" style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="/images/default_avatar.png" /></a>

  <div class="menu-container">
    <ul class="user-menu" style="list-style:none;">
      <li class="user-menu__item"><a class="user-menu-link" href="/member.php">Profile</a></li>
      <li class="user-menu__item"><a class="user-menu-link" href="/private.php">Messages</a></li>
      <li class="user-menu__item"><a class="user-menu-link" href="/friends">Friends</a></li>
      <li class="user-menu__item"><a class="user-menu-link" href="/view-alerts">Alerts</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
```

```
    document.querySelector('.mini-photo-wrapper').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.menu-container').classList.toggle('active');
});
```

Comment: Typically you will attach event listener to the document body.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how that would work please?

Comment: It's late and I'm lazy, but this looks like a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33060993/click-outside-div-to-hide-div-in-pure-javascript/33061018

Comment: that code is different, but thanks anyway, maybe someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = function(){
  var divToHide = document.getElementById('divToHide');
  document.onclick = function(e){
    if(e.target.id !== 'divToHide'){
      document.querySelector('.menu-container').classList.remove('active');
    }
  };
};
```

I almost literally copy-pasted this. If there is only one item on the page, prefer id over class like in this example.

Comment: Every link on the page now opens the menu, what am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for all of your help, but with the new edit, the dropdown no longer opens, sorry