# remove.EventListener() is changing how the program works

Tags: javascript, html, removeeventlistener

I am trying to do a div that appears when I click in one div and then disappear when I click out of it, I used a EventListener() to do it and the progrmam works fine without the removeEventListener(), but I need the to remove the EventListener() so the div can disappear when I click in the same div that makes it show.

When I use the removeEventListener() the event.target changes

On the code: [object HTMLBodyElement]

Off the code: [object HTMLDivElement]

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="account-settings gear m-r-120">
  <!-- ACCOUNT SETTINGS -->

  <span class="gear" onclick="settings()">
    <i class="fas fa-cog fa-2x gear"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-down gear m-t-7 p-l-5"></i>
  </span>
</div>
<!-- ACCOUNT SETTINGS -->

<div class="settings-box trigger" id="settings-box" style="display: none">
  <!-- SETTINGS BOX -->

  <div class="change-box trigger">
    <a href="#" class="trigger"> Change Name </a>
  </div>

  <div class="change-box trigger">
    <a href="#" class="trigger"> Change Password </a>
  </div>

  <div class="change-box trigger">
    <a href="#" class="trigger"> Change Email </a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- SETTINGS BOX -->
```

JS:

```
function settings() {
  var box = document.getElementById("settings-box");

  if (box.style.display === "none") {
    document.addEventListener("click", setBox);

    function setBox() {
      let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("trigger");
      let gear = document.getElementsByClassName("gear");
      var click = false;

      for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i] === event.target) {
          click = true;
        }
      }

      if (!click) {
        for (let j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
          if (gear[j] === event.target) {
            click = true;
          }
        }
      }

      if (click === false) {
        box.style.display = "none";
        this.removeEventListener("click", setBox);
      } else {
        box.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
  } else {
    box.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** - [Click outside div to hide div in pure JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33060993/click-outside-div-to-hide-div-in-pure-javascript) - question about the same problem, take a look.

Looks like you're using `removeEventListener()` wrong. You need to remove the listener only when you don't need to trigger your div visibility anymore. You can simplify your logic, just change the display of `#settings-box` when you click on the `.gear` span, without any `addEventListener`, because you use onclick handler. To show\hide div, I suggest using **data attribute** - [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Should be something like this:

HTML

```
<div class="account-settings gear m-r-120">
  <span class="gear" onclick="settings()">
    <i class="fas fa-cog fa-2x gear"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-down gear m-t-7 p-l-5"></i>
  </span>
</div>

<!-- Add data attribute here!! --!>
<div 
  data-hidden="true"
  class="settings-box trigger"
  id="settings-box"
  style="display: none;"
>  
  <div class="change-box trigger">
    <a href="#" class="trigger">
      Change Name
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="change-box trigger">
    <a href="#" class="trigger">
      Change Password
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="change-box trigger">
    <a href="#" class="trigger">
      Change Email
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you see, I add a data-hidden attribute, **we will use it to track the visibility of the div.**

JS:

```
function settings(){
  var box = document.getElementById("settings-box");
  // Gets hidden attribute.
  var isHIdden = box.dataset.hidden;
  if (!isHidden) {
    // if hidden attribute is missing then
    // we hide div and add hidden attribute.
    box.style.display = "none";
    box.dataset.hidden = "true";
  } else {
    // If hidden attribute is set then we show div
    // and remove hidden attribute.
    box.style.display = "block";
    box.removeAttribute("hidden");
  }
}
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: but will the div become hidden again if I click somewhere out of it?

Comment: Take a look at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33060993/click-outside-div-to-hide-div-in-pure-javascript - there is very similar functionality needed

Comment: ty, but I don't think this will help, it's the same problem I have when I click to open it will not open beacuse I'm already cliking outside