# Closing Div on click outside of div

Tags: javascript, html, display, mouseup

I'm trying to close a contact form Div when clicking outside of the div. I got it working so that it closes outside of the Div, but the form also closes when clicking the Div. Does anyone know why this could be happening? I appreciate any tips.

HTML Code:

```
  <div class="formPopup" id="myForm">
<main class="mainElement">
  <button class="closeBtn" onclick="closeForm()">X</button>
  <form class="contactForm" action="contact.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
    <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="your email address">
    <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="subject">
    <textarea class="message" name="message" placeholder="message"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn">SEND <MAIL></MAIL></button>
  </main>
```

JS code:

```
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){ if (event.target != $(".mainElement") {
document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";}});
```

Comment: `if (event.target != $(".mainElement")` lacks a `)` and the comparison will never be `true` as you can’t compare objects like this. Use `if(event.target.closest(".mainElement"))`. You don’t need jQuery here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Click outside div to hide div in pure JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33060993/click-outside-div-to-hide-div-in-pure-javascript)