# how to close the sidebar when clicking outside?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a noobie at programing. I'm currently making a simple shop website for a project in class. I'm currently struggling with how to make it work.

This is my complete style sheet

```
     <style>
        .open{
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: black;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 40px; 
        }
        
        .open i {
            color: white;
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
        }
        
        #Sidenav {
            height: 100%;
            width: 0px; 
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 1; 
            top: 0; 
            left: 0; 
            background-color: black;
            overflow-x: hidden; 
            transition: 0.5s; 
        }
        
        .logo {
            margin: 20px 0 0 0; /* top right down left */
            width: 75%;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid white;
        }
        
        .logo img {
            margin: 0;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            
        }
        
        .sidenav ul {
            margin: 0 0 0 12.5%;/* top right down left */
            padding: 0;
            width: 75%;
            list-style: none;
        }
          
        .sidenav ul li a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: black;
            position: relative;
        }
        
        .sidenav ul li{
            margin: 10px 0 10px 0; /* top right down left */
            background-color: white;
            border-radius: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 30px;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
    </style>
```

All of HTML codes are working fine

```
<body>
    <span class="open" onclick="OpenNav()"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>/* My button */

    <nav id="Sidenav" class="sidenav">
            
            <center>
                <div class="logo">   
                    <<img src="#" alt="logo"/>
                <div>
            </center>
            
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">All Items</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Smartphones</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Appliances</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PC Components</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Software</a></li>
                
                <li><a href="#">My Cart</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Shop Inventory</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    
    <h1>Content
    <div id="main">
        
    </div>
```

The function OpenNav() work fine as well, but when I put the Closenav function I can't click on anything else.

```
    <script>
        function OpenNav() {
          document.getElementById("Sidenav").style.width = "250px";
        }

        document.onclick = function(Closenav){
           if(Closenav.target.id !== 'Sidenav'){
              document.getElementById("Sidenav").style.width = "0px";
           };
        };
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33060993/click-outside-div-to-hide-div-in-pure-javascript follow this link, the same question as yours

Comment: When you click on `OpenNav` you also click on `document`. Hence when you click to show you get 1) `set width 250px` 2) `set width 0px` in quick succession.

Comment: There are also some issues with your HTML. I.e. unclosed div, and h1 + extra `<` before image.

Comment: Thank you @Omar Zaoujal, I manipulated some of the javascript and it finally worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the idea is to wrap up your sidebar or the content of it in a div with a fixed position and width / height 100% and then you will listen to this wrapper's click.
This way is similar of how Bootstrap handles modals, and also it will help you if you want to add a blurry effect to the page when the sidebar is open.